# Count where Column is True, Grouped By Another in Pandas

Tags: pandas

Given a DataFrame like this:

```
dft = pd.DataFrame([[12, 'Bob', True], 
                   [123, 'Henry', False], 
                   [768, 'Bob', False]], 
                   columns=['TID', 'UID', 'TRUTH'])
```

Which looks like this:

```
   TID    UID  TRUTH
0   12    Bob   True
1  123  Henry  False
3  768    Bob  False
```

I want to aggregate over `UID` and count where `TRUTH` is True.  So the output should look like:

```
     UID  TRUTH
0    Bob      1
1  Henry      0
```

I have already tried:

```
 dft.groupby('UID').agg({'TRUTH': pd.Series.nunique})  # counts all values T and F
```

I am conceptually struggling to see how to put the condition together with the aggregation.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
print(dft.groupby('UID')['TRUTH'].sum().astype(int))
```

Output:

```
UID
Bob      1
Henry    0
Name: TRUTH, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Although I am concerned that this solution may not generalise to other conditions.  For example if TRUTH was instead ACTION \in {'Add', 'Delete', 'Edit'}, and I wanted to count the number of Adds, I'm not sure if this approach would work?

Comment: @Hanshan This solution is an answer to your question where the `TRUTH` column only contains boolean values. Thus, this solution only works under the conditions presented in your question. If there are other conditions, those conditions should have been indicated in your question. I don't recommend that you edit your post now, when your original question is already answered. You should probably post an other question, describing the new conditions you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: Yes indeed.  I had changed the title before your answer to mention a general "condition", and I believe there are possibly more and less generally applicable answers, but I do believe you are right in what you say.  I will change the title back to the more specific one, and open a new question - as I do have to count actions next!